# Squeeze theorem on expression with minus

Tags: calculus

This is a question from an exam on calculus.
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }(-6e^{11x} + 9sin(x) + 3e^{8x} )^{8/4x} $$

I tried this:

$$ (3e^{(8x)})^{(8/4x)} < (-6e^{11x} + 9sin(x) + 3e^{8x} )^{8/4x} < (3e^{8x}+3e^{8x}+3e^{8x} )^{8/4x} $$

However, I'm not sure if it's right.
The problem is:
$ (3e^{(8x)})^{(8/4x)} < (-6e^{11x} + 9sin(x) + 3e^{8x} )^{8/4x} $

If it was $+6e$ instead of $-6e$,then I am sure that it's true, because it's make sense that the middle expression is bigger, because the middle expression is the same like the left side , only with more additions. but...

There is a minus on the middle expression, how can I know that
$ (3e^{(8x)})^{(8/4x)} < (-6e^{11x} + 9sin(x) + 3e^{8x} )^{8/4x} $ is really true?

Can I use the squeeze theorem on this exercise?

Comment: Do you *need/want* to use the squeeze theorem, or just want to compute the limit? There is IMHO a much faster way to compute it

Comment: sorry, but isn't $-6 e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3 e^{8x}<0$ for large $x$? Then your limit is not properly defined...

Comment: @Pierpaolo Vivo I just want to compute the limit. I don't know what is mean limit not defined. you mean that there is no limit? this is a question from end of semester exam, and according to the exam solution there is limit , e^2 , which is properly wrong because in wolfram the solution is e^22

Comment: Take $x=5$. Your function $(3 \exp (8 x)-6 \exp (11 x)+9 \sin (x))^{2/x}$ computed for $x=5$ is $=2.26841\times 10^9+6.98145\times 10^9 \mathrm{i}$. It is a complex number. Your question is not conceptually different from asking: what is the limit $\lim_{x\to -5}\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your lecturer is rather cheeky, or there is a typo in your question. The function
$$
h(x)=-6 e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3 e^{8x}
$$
is badly negative for $x\to +\infty$. Take the limit $x\to +\infty$. You can compute it easily as
$$
e^{11x}\left(-6 +9\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{11x}}+3 e^{-3x}\right)\to -\infty
$$
(where *en passant* you can also use the squeeze theorem to show that $\sin(x)/e^{11x}\to 0$ !). Therefore, your limit is not properly defined on the reals, as the domain of a function of the form $h(x)^{w(x)}$ is $h(x)>0$ (otherwise you cannot use the step $h(x)^{w(x)}=\exp(w(x)\ln h(x)$).

Comment: there is no typo. I checked. the solution is e^2 . but he didn't use squeeze thorem

Comment: Well, it is a fact that you cannot raise a *negative* function to another function within the reals. You can do it only using the principal value of a logarithm in the complex plane, which I doubt that is what you were requested to do during the exam. If you try to plot either the $h(x)$ of my answer, or your original function, you will see confirmation of my statement. You cannot even *plot* your function for large $x$!

Comment: the same function is in the exam answers and in the exam solution pdf file so I don't think that there is a 2 typos . I can send an email to the lecturer but can you please explain the problem in simple English so I can translate it? or please make it shorter and I send it as is

Comment: I asked the lecturer this question in the class. you were right. the limit is not belong to "R" field.  he was surprised that this question was in the exam.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(-6e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3e^{8x}\right)^{\frac{8}{4x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(-6e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3e^{8x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left[\ln\left(\left(-6e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3e^{8x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}\right)\right]=$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\left[\frac{2}{x}\ln\left(-6e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3e^{8x}\right)\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\ln\left(-6e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3e^{8x}\right)}{x}\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(2\ln\left(-6e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3e^{8x}\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)}\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{8e^{8x}-22e^{11x}+3\cos(x)}{e^{8x}-2e^{11x}+3\sin(x)}}{1}\right]=$$
$$\exp\left[2\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{8e^{8x}-22e^{11x}+3\cos(x)}{e^{8x}-2e^{11x}+3\sin(x)}\right]=$$
$$\exp[2\cdot11]=\exp[22]=e^{22}$$

Comment: can you confirm that $-6 e^{11x}+9\sin(x)+3 e^{8x}<0$ for large $x$? If yes, the function is not properly defined, right? [we cannot take the \exp(\log(.))]